# Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, .net, properties, frameworks, windows

```
public partial class frmManager : Form
{
    public String Name
    {
        get 
        {
            txtName.Text;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the getter and setter and define a custom getter you also need to define a custom setter.
 For eg :

```
    public String Name
    {
        get { return txtName.Text; }
        set { txtName.Text = value; }
    }
```

Or you can create "getonly" properties :

```
    public String Name
    {
        get { return txtName.Text; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change that to:

```
public partial class frmManager : Form
{
    public String Name
    {
        get 
        {
            return txtName.Text;
        }
        set;  // you may also want to change this to set the value of txtName.Text (txtName.Text = value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return` in the get method:

```c#
public partial class frmManager : Form
{
    public String Name
    {
        get 
        {
            return txtName.Text;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

The error (CS0201):

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

occurred because the statement `txtName.Text;` in the `get` method doesn't actually do anything.  Similar statements in C and C++ are legal, but may trigger compiler warnings such as "statement has no effect".  C# protects against this programming mistake by enforcing a syntactic restriction that prohibits these statements.